# writing csv from web site crawling in python

Tags: python, csv

I have just start learnings programming and now I have a problem
I have written a crawling code which goes to multiple web pages and the problem I have is that I need to save the data as CSV file in two columns `source(webpage),target(link)` to be readable for Excel but have like 8k web pages and I want to set them with 75k links

To be more specific this is the output that I'm looking for:
so this is the code I have

```
url = "https://ontariotechu.ca"
html = urllib.request.urlopen(url, context=ctx).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tags = soup('a')
for tag in tags:
   w.append(tag.get('href'))
```

and this how I want to store my data

[image]

Comment: So did you try using `DictWriter`? Give a [mre] to show your current implementation and the specific problem with it.

Comment: You're making this too complicated.  `print( "%s,%s" % (url, tag.get('href')))`.

Comment: @TimRoberts oh thanks I got what I wanted